# BigQuery results display "null" for a parameter value of an event for iOS devices but is populated in DebugView

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have an event that is triggered along with the parameters and its values when a particular action is completed on the App.
We've made this change for both iOS and Android apps.

The issue I am facing is that for iOS when I try to fetch data in BigQuery this parameter value is "null" for this event.

We set up debugView in Firebase console and on triggering this event on an iOS device we observed the said parameter value being populated in the event.

I assume my query is also correct since the BigQuery results show this value for Android devices.

Has someone faced such an issue?

SDK Versions used

```
react-native-firebase: 5.3.1
iOS SDK version: 5.19.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out.

For some reason for the events triggered on iOS these values are populated as "double" values and not int. Not sure why since our codebase triggers this as int type

Comment: So what was the fix?